# sporadic app loading issues with Debugger for Chrome in VS Code

Tags: angular, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm having issues with the remote debugger for Chrome in Visual Studio Code.  Actually the problem is with the Firefox debugger, too, so it's not just a Chrome issue.  Everything will work fine for a while and then I'll encounter an issue where instead of my Angular 2 app loading on localhost, the browser is behaving as if it's trying to open a file resource rather than an HTTP resource.

And this is happening regardless if I run the instance of Chrome in an isolated environment or not.  Here's my launch.json file (with userDataDir to run in an isolated browser):

{

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:4000",
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "userDataDir": "C:\\temp\\chrome-dev-configuration"
}]
```

}

So in the browser when this issue occurs, I'll see this instead of my app loading:

[image]

And in the console here are the errors:

[image]

If I close all the browser windows and VS Code, and restart VS Code and start over, the problem goes away, but not all the time, or at least not right away.  This is very annoying and confusing, to say the least.  I'm sticking with Firefox debugging of my Angular 2 app outside of VS Code, as its user experience is better than Chrome, especially when working with Typescript files, so I'll stick with that for now, unless I can figure this out.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I would expect to see this if you had set `"port": 4000` in your launch config, or had launched chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=4000`, but it looks like you aren't doing that...

Comment: You see this with Firefox too? This is a Chrome specific page AFAIK

Comment: I do have the --remote-debugging-port=4000 set when I launch Chrome.  And yes, this happened with Firefox, too.  I just didn't show the launch.json file or the Firefox devtools screenshot with the same error.

Comment: Ok, don't do that. That's the port that Chrome uses for the debugging connection. You can't run your webserver on the same port.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what the port setting in Chrome meant.  I thought it has to be for the port of the web app, but you're saying that's not the case?

So should I run the web app under a different port or can I specify the debugging connection port for Chrome as something else and keep the app at 4000?  I see port 9222 is the default in the launch.json file when it's created.

Comment: Right, for a 'launch'-type config, you don't need to specify the port. For an 'attach' config, you can use whatever ports you want. As long as they're different.

Comment: I am still confused on ports. By default, vscode puts "url": "http:/localhost:8080" for launch and "port": 9222 for attach. If the server runs on 5555, what should these be for attaching or launching?